# MySQL select row from one table with multiple rows in a second table and get array of multi row in selected row

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

i have one table containing "Client" information, and another including "Tickets" information for each client.

```
int-------| varchar -------| varchar
client_id | client_name    | client_tickets
----------+----------------+--------------
1         | Title one      | 1,2
2         | Title two      | 2,3
```

Simplified tickets table

```
int--------| varchar -------| varchar
ticket_id  | ticket_name | ticket_price
-----------+-------------+--------------
1          | ticketone   | 30  
2          | tickettwo   | 40   
3          | ticketthree | 50  
4          | ticketfour  | 60   
5          | ticketfive  | 70
```

With the above two tables, I want to produce a single table with a single query with all the pertinent information to generate a search grid
So as to give the following output :

```
client_id | client_name    | client_tickets | ticket_names          | ticket_prices
----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+--
1         | Title one      | 1,2            | ticketone,tickettwo   | 30,40
2         | Title two      | 2,3            | tickettwo,ticketthree | 40,50
```

ticket_names,ticket_ids,client_name are varchar

I want to receive the final 5 columns with one request
for example :

```
SELECT s.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ticket_name SEPARATOR ',') FROM tickets_table WHERE ticket_id IN(s.client_tickets)) AS ticket_names, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ticket_price SEPARATOR ',') FROM tickets_table WHERE ticket_id IN(s.client_tickets)) AS ticket_prices 
FROM client_table s where s.client_id=1
```

Which seems to have a problem
Do you have a better suggestion?

Please make your suggestions

**Update :**
To clean the result I want
The following code has two querys,
I want this code to be done with a query

```
$client_result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM client_table where client_id=1");
while($client_row = $client_result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $ticket_result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tickets_table where ticket_id IN ($client_row['client_tickets'])");
  while($ticket_row = ticket_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $ticket_row['ticket_name']."<br>";
  }
}
```

**update 2**

i use suggest @raxi , but my mariadb is 10.4.17-MariaDB and don't support JSON_ARRAYAGG , for resolve it according to the reference Creating an [aggregate function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-aggregate-functions/)
, Using SQL

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS JSON_ARRAYAGG//

CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS JSON_ARRAYAGG(next_value TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN  

 DECLARE json TEXT DEFAULT '[""]';
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN json_remove(json, '$[0]');
      LOOP  
          FETCH GROUP NEXT ROW;
          SET json = json_array_append(json, '$', next_value);
      END LOOP;  

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And do you want to keep the tables as-is ? or would you prefer to see a schema that'll make things easier (the join query is totally different between the 2 situations)

Comment: No, if there is a better way, then I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want a fairly straightforward `SELECT` query with some `LEFT/INNER JOIN`(s).

This website has some good examples/explanations which seem very close to your need: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

---

I would give you a quick working example, but it is not really clear to me what datatype the relevant columns are. Both tables' `_id`-columns are likely some variant of INTEGER, are they also both primary keys (or otherwise atleast indexed ?), the `client_name`/`ticket_name` are likely VARCHAR/TEXT/STRING types, but how exactly is the remaining column stored? as json or array or ? (+details)

Also you tagged your post with `PHP`, are you just after the SQL query ? or looking for PHP code with the SQL inside it.

---

**updated**

## Improved version of the schema

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    client_id      SERIAL,
    client_name    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tickets (
    ticket_id      SERIAL,
    ticket_name    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    ticket_price   DECIMAL(10,2)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
);

-- A junction table to glue those 2 tables together (N to N relationship)
CREATE TABLE client_tickets (
    client_id      BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ticket_id      BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id, ticket_id)
);
```

I have changed the datatypes.
`client_name` and `ticket_name` are still VARCHARS. I've flagged them as `NOT NULL` (eg: required fields), but you can remove that part if you don't like that.
`client_id`/`ticket_id`/`ticket_price` are also `NOT NULL` but changing that has negative side-effects.

`ticket_price` is now a DECIMAL field, which can store numbers such as `1299.50` or `50.00`  The `(10,2)` bit means it covers every possible number up to 8 whole digits (dollars/euros/whatever), and 2 decimals (cents). so you can store anything from $ -*99.999.999,99* to $ *99.999.999,99* .
in SQL always write numbers (like lets say 70k) in this notation: `70000.00` (eg: a dot, not a comma; and no thousandseperators).

`client_id` and `ticket_id` are both `SERIAL`s now, which is shorthand for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE` and theyre both `PRIMARY KEY`s on top of that. That probably sounds complicated but they're still just ordinary `INTEGER`s with values like `4` or `12` etc.

The `UNIQUE` bit prevents you from having 2 clients with the same ID number, and the `AUTO_INCREMENT` means that when you add a new client, you dont have to specify an ID (though you are allowed to); you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO clients (client_name) values ('Fantastic Mr Fox');
```

and the `client_id` will automatically be set (incrementing over time). And the same goes for `ticket_id` in the other table.

.

I've replaced your original `client_tickets` column, into a separate junction table.
Records in there store the `client_id` of a client and the `ticket_id` that belongs to them.
A client can have multiple records in the junction table (one record for each ticket they own).
Likewise, a ticket can be mentioned on any number of rows.
It's possible for a certain `client_id` to not have any records in the junction table.
Likewise, it's possible for a certain `ticket_id` to not have any records in the junction table.
Identical records cannot exist in this table (enforced by `PRIMARY KEY`).

## Testdata

Next, we can put some data in there to be able to test it:

```
    -- Create some tickets
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (1, 'ticketone',    '30' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (2, 'tickettwo',    '40' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (3, 'ticketthree',  '50' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (4, 'ticketfour',   '60' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (5, 'ticketfive',   '70' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (6, 'ticketsix',     '4' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (7, 'ticketseven',   '9' );
    INSERT INTO  tickets (ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_price) values (8, 'ticketeight', '500' );
    
    -- Create some users, and link them to some of these tickets
    INSERT INTO  clients (client_id, client_name) values (1, 'John');
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (1, 3);
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (1, 7);
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (1, 1);
    
    INSERT INTO  clients (client_id, client_name) values (2, 'Peter');
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (2, 5);
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (2, 2);
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (2, 3);
    
    INSERT INTO  clients (client_id, client_name) values (3, 'Eddie');
    INSERT INTO  client_tickets (client_id, ticket_id) values (3, 8);
    
    INSERT INTO  clients (client_id, client_name) values (9, 'Fred');
    
    -- Note: ticket #3 is owned by both client #1/#2; 
    -- Note: ticket #4 and #6 are unused; 
    -- Note: client #9 (Fred) has no tickets;
```

## Queries

Get all the existing relationships (ticket-less clients are left out & owner-less tickets are left out)

```
            SELECT clients.*
                 , tickets.*
              FROM client_tickets AS ct
        INNER JOIN clients ON ct.client_id = clients.client_id
        INNER JOIN tickets ON ct.ticket_id = tickets.ticket_id
          ORDER BY clients.client_id ASC
                 , tickets.ticket_id ASC ;
```

Get all the tickets that are still free (owner-less)

```
            SELECT tickets.*
              FROM tickets
             WHERE tickets.ticket_id NOT IN (
                        SELECT ct.ticket_id
                          FROM client_tickets AS ct
                   )
          ORDER BY tickets.ticket_id ASC ;
```

Get a list of ALL clients (even ticketless ones), and include how many tickets each has and the total price of their tickets.

```
            SELECT clients.*
                 , COALESCE(COUNT(tickets.ticket_id),     0)  AS  amount_of_tickets
                 , COALESCE(SUM(tickets.ticket_price), 0.00)  AS  total_price
              FROM clients
         LEFT JOIN client_tickets AS ct  ON ct.client_id = clients.client_id
         LEFT JOIN tickets               ON ct.ticket_id = tickets.ticket_id
          GROUP BY clients.client_id
          ORDER BY clients.client_id ASC ;
```

Put all the juicy info together (owner-less tickets are left out)

```
            SELECT clients.*
                 , COALESCE(COUNT(sub.ticket_id),       0)  AS  amount_of_tickets
                 , COALESCE(SUM(sub.ticket_price),   0.00)  AS  total_price
                 , JSON_ARRAYAGG(sub.js_tickets_row)        AS  js_tickets_rows
              FROM clients
         LEFT JOIN client_tickets AS ct  ON  ct.client_id = clients.client_id
         LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT tickets.*
                             , JSON_OBJECT( 'ticket_id',    tickets.ticket_id
                                          , 'ticket_name',  tickets.ticket_name
                                          , 'ticket_price', tickets.ticket_price
                                          )  AS js_tickets_row
                          FROM tickets
                   ) AS sub ON ct.ticket_id = sub.ticket_id
          GROUP BY clients.client_id
          ORDER BY clients.client_id ASC ;
          
          -- sidenote: output column `js_tickets_rows` (a json array) may contain NULL values
```

An list of all tickets with some aggregate data

```
            SELECT tickets.*
                 , IF(COALESCE(COUNT(clients.client_id), 0) > 0
                     , TRUE, FALSE)                                      AS  active
                 , COALESCE(    COUNT(clients.client_id), 0)             AS  amount_of_clients
                 , IF(COALESCE( COUNT(clients.client_id), 0) > 0
                     , GROUP_CONCAT(clients.client_name SEPARATOR ', ')
                     , NULL)                                             AS  client_names
              FROM tickets
         LEFT JOIN client_tickets AS ct  ON ct.ticket_id = tickets.ticket_id
         LEFT JOIN clients               ON ct.client_id = clients.client_id
          GROUP BY tickets.ticket_id
          ORDER BY tickets.ticket_id ASC 
                 , clients.client_id ASC ;
```

---

Comment: question is updated.. plz check it ,

Comment: thanks , but value client_tickets = (1,2) means that (ticket_id IN (1,2))
OR means ( ticket_id=1 OR ticket_id=2 )
comma is Separator for tickets id

Comment: According to your answer, a ticket must be created for each client_id,
But we want to use some pre-made tickets marked in the client_tickets column with a comma separator

Comment: i updated question, the required output was written with two queries,
But I need to get this output with a query

Comment: Hmm i see, yea i didnt fully grasp the idea of the tickets then, but in that case, should it be possible for say ticket 6 to apply to more than 1 client ? (im assuming no?) and is it literally always 2 tickets ? (never 1 or 3 or 4 etc) -- it'll be an easy change; i'll update the examples if you can clarify those tickets a bit;

Comment: should it be possible for say ticket 6 to apply to more than 1 client ? answer : YES . .. is it literally always 2 tickets ? answer: NO.... it can be (never 1 or  2 or 3 or 4 etc)

Comment: We have a ticket table and a customer table,
In the customer table, we have determined which tickets the customer has bought
For example, customer number one has bought tickets number 1, 2, 5.
Now we want the customer tickets details to be displayed for us along with the customer information in the output format with a query

Comment: I have updated the answer (incl all queries) to include a junction table. That allows for N to N relationships which is the most flexible implementation which supports your needs as i understand it.

Comment: thanks , your solution is helpful for me, But in your solution, the client can only choose one ticket,
While the client may have two or more tickets at the same time.
Anyway, thank you.
I'm trying to change my schema

Comment: No the version with the junction table allows any possible variation (often refered to as `N to N`). For every extra ticket a client has , you just `INSERT` another row into the junction table. When you want to take a ticket away from a user you `DELETE FROM client_tickets WHERE client_id=3 and ticket_id=77`

Comment: ohhh! yes , sorry , its true, 
It did not work for me because 10.4.17-MariaDB don't support JSON_ARRAYAGG. 
Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Yea, you can get the same information without the use of JSON by using either the first and/or third of the SELECT queries i listed above. They contain the same information but using the traditional SQL layout. the 4th query which uses json was more included because your original example involved having multiple descendant objects in a column (your comma-separated id's), but it's not something i particularly recommend here. SELECT queries 1,2,3 & 5 can likely provide you all the info you need ; and you can of course use WHERE clauses to filter them too.

Comment: thanks, i sloved it by update 2

Comment: its OK , @Raxi , best regards ...